# OOP PHP PDO, Page function doesn't work (UserCake)

Tags: php, mysql, oop, usercake

I'm doing my own little project converting UserCake (latest) to OOP with PDO, i've finalised a lot of features already. But right now i've been stuck for awhile on this Page functionality. So according to the code it's suppose to read the root folder for PHP files and add them to DB table (uc_pages) if they don't already exist. And if there's pages in the DB that doesn't exist in the root folder to delete those from the db.

I get no errors at all which is kinda interesting... but i'll post the code if anyone would be kind to give me a hand on this one.

**Pages.php**

```
<?php 
require_once("resources/database.php"); 
$website_pages = new dbPages($db); 

// set number of records per page 
$records_per_page = 6;  

// calculate for the query LIMIT clause 
$from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page; 

$website_pages->getPageFiles(); 
//Retrieve list of pages in root usercake folder 
$website_pages->fetchAllPages(); 
//Retrieve list of pages in pages table 
$creations = array(); 
$deletions = array(); 

//Check if any pages exist which are not in DB 
foreach ($website_pages->getPageFiles() as $web_page){ 
    if(!isset($website_pages->readOne()[$web_page])){ 
        $creations[] = $web_page; 
    } 
} 

//Enter new pages in DB if found 
if (count($creations) > 0) { 
    $website_pages->create($creations); 
} 

if (count($website_pages->fetchAllPages()) > 0){ 
    //Check if DB contains pages that don't exist 
    foreach ($website_pages->readOne() as $web_page){ 
      if(!isset($website_pages->fetchAllPages()[$web_page['page']])){ 
            $deletions[] = $web_page['id'];     
        } 
    } 
} 

//Delete pages from DB if not found 
if (count($deletions) > 0) { 
    $website_pages->delete($deletions); 
} 

//Update DB pages 
$website_pages->readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page); 

// header settings 
$page_url="pages.php?"; 
$page_title = "UNFINISHED: All pages"; 
include_once "./resources/header.php"; 
?> 
<div class='container'> 
<div class='page-header'> 
<h1><?php echo"{$page_title}";?></h1> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="jumbotron"> 
<div class="container"> 
<?php  
// query products 
$stmt = $website_pages->readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page); 
$num = $stmt->rowCount(); 

// display the products if there are any 
if($num>0){ 

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
            extract($row); 
            echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'> 
   <div class='btn-group btn-group-justified' role='group' 
   aria-label='Justified button group'> 
   <a href='page.php?id={$id}' class='btn btn-warning' role='button'> 
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</a> 
            </div>"; 
            echo " 
            <div class='panel panel-primary'> 
            <div class='panel-heading'> 
                <h3 class='panel-title'>{$page_name}</h3> 
            </div> 
            <div class='panel-footer'>"; 
            //Show public/private setting of page 
            if($private == 0){ 
                echo "This page is Public"; 
            } 
            else { 
                echo "This page is Private";     
            } 
            echo "</div></div></div>"; 
} 
    echo "</div>"; 
    // needed for paging 
    $total_rows=0; 

    if($page_url=="pages.php?"){ 
        $total_rows=$website_pages->countAll(); 
    } 

    // paging buttons 
    include_once './resources/paging.php'; 
} 

// tell the user there are no products 
else{ 
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">"; 
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data- 
        dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>"; 
        echo "No pages found."; 
    echo "</div>"; 
} 
echo "</div>"; 
?> 
</div> 
</div> 
<?php require("./resources/footer.php")?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php 
class Database{ 

    // specify your own database credentials 
    private $host = "###########"; 
    private $db_name = "website"; 
    private $username = "###########"; 
    private $password = "###########"; 
    public $conn; 

    // get the database connection 
    public function getConnection(){ 

        $this->conn = null; 

        try{ 
            $this->conn = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, 
        $this->username, $this->password); 
        }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage(); 
        } 

        return $this->conn; 
    } 
} 
// instantiate database and product object 
$database = new Database(); 
$db = $database->getConnection(); 
require_once './resources/functions.php'; 
$website = new Configuration($db); 
$website->readConfig(); 
?>
```

**The part from functions.php that is struggling**

```
class dbPages { 
    // database connection and table names 
    private $conn; 
    private $table_name = "uc_pages"; 
    private $table_name2 = "uc_permission_page_matches"; 

    // object properties 
    public $id; 
    public $page_id; 
    public $permission_id; 
    public $page_name; 
    public $private; 
    public $pages; 
    public $row; 

    public function __construct($db){ 
        $this->conn = $db; 
    } 

    //Retrieve a list of all .php files in root files folder 
    function getPageFiles() { 
        $directory = ""; 
        $pages = glob($directory . "*.php"); 
        //print each file name 
        foreach ($pages as $web_page){ 
            $row[$web_page] = $web_page; 
        } 
        return $row; 
    } 

    //Fetch information on all pages 
    function fetchAllPages() {  
        $query = "SELECT  
                    id, 
                    page_name,  
                    private 
                FROM  
                    " . $this->table_name . " "; 
        // prepare query statement 
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ); 
        $stmt->execute();         

        while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
            $row[$web_page] = array(
'id' => $id, 'page_name' =>   $page_name, 'private' => $private); 
        } 
        if (isset($row)){ 
            return ($row); 
        } 
    } 

    // read products 
    function readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page){ 
        // select query 
        $query = "SELECT  
                    id, 
                    page_name,  
                    private 
                FROM  
                    " . $this->table_name . " 
                ORDER BY  
                    page_name ASC  
                LIMIT  
                    ?, ?"; 
        // prepare query statement 
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ); 

        // bind variable values 
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT); 

        // execute query 
        $stmt->execute(); 

        // return values from database 
        return $stmt; 
    } 

    // used for paging products 
    public function countAll(){ 
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows 
        FROM " . $this->table_name . ""; 

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        return $row['total_rows']; 
    } 

    // used when filling up the update product form 
    function readOne(){ 
        $query = "SELECT  
                    id,  
                    page_name,  
                    private  
                FROM  
                    " . $this->table_name . "  
                WHERE  
                    page_name = ? 
                LIMIT  
                    0,1"; 

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ); 
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id); 
        $stmt->execute(); 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        $this->id = $row['id']; 
        $this->page_name = $row['page_name']; 
        $this->private = $row['private']; 
    } 

    // create product 
    function create($pages){ 
        //write query 
        $query = "INSERT INTO  
                    " . $this->table_name . "  
                SET  
                    id = ?,  
                    page_name = ?,  
                    private = ?"; 

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id); 
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->page_name); 
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->private); 
        foreach($pages as $page_name){         
            if($stmt->execute()){ 
                return true; 
            }else{ 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    // delete the product 
    function delete($pages){ 
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?"; 
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id); 

        foreach($pages as $id){ 
            if($result = $stmt->execute()){ 
                return true; 
            }else{ 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
        $query2 = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name2 . " 
        WHERE page_id = ?"; 
        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare($query); 
        $stmt2->bindParam(1, $this->page_id); 

        foreach($pages as $id){ 
            if($result = $stmt2->execute()){ 
                return true; 
            }else{ 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Joakim, you should be aware that Usercake's codebase is outdated and no longer being actively maintained by the creators.  

Not sure how far along you are in your project, but you might want to check out [UserFrosting](http://www.userfrosting.com), my spinoff of UC that **is** being actively developed and maintained. It is already OOP and builds on some newer components like Slim and Twig.

Comment: I wound up getting all these functions to work properly in the latest beta of UserSpice. Let me know if you're still looking for help on this.